# pyplot.hist histtype = 'step' malfunction depending on data

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I was doing a lot of plotting and ran into a weird anomaly with the pyplot.hist function. I've trimmed my program down to the minimum working example to show the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
var = [25.00, 35.68, 29.02, 25.46, 30.58, 30.86, 38.08, 38.63,
       25.19, 32.11, 26.57, 37.23, 37.97, 27.38, 27.25, 33.33,
       31.41, 26.93, 28.42, 25.99, 30.09, 31.87, 34.40, 33.46,
       31.76, 34.03, 27.01, 27.52, 30.41, 25.84, 25.84]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.hist(var, histtype = 'step')
plt.show()
```

When I run the script, I get this:

[Anomaly http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13695305/Figure%201_005.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13695305/Figure%201_005.png)

However, if I remove the **last 5** elements: 27.01, 27.52, 30.41, 25.84, 25.84, then the script works fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
var = [25.00, 35.68, 29.02, 25.46, 30.58, 30.86, 38.08, 38.63,
       25.19, 32.11, 26.57, 37.23, 37.97, 27.38, 27.25, 33.33,
       31.41, 26.93, 28.42, 25.99, 30.09, 31.87, 34.40, 33.46,
       31.76, 34.03]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.hist(var, histtype = 'step')
plt.show()
```

[Working! http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13695305/Figure%201_004.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13695305/Figure%201_004.png)

This is driving me crazy! I've tried using numpy arrays, and that didn't help. Numpy random worked no problem. But for some reason, my specific data set (type?) causes it to fail. Does anyone have any idea why?

Edit: It is important to note that the function works fine with histtype = 'bar', but the bug arises with histtype = 'step'. Hopefully someone can recreate this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [it's a bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2061), but there's a fix:  Manually set the `ymin` for your plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

var = [[25.00, 35.68, 29.02, 25.46, 30.58, 30.86, 38.08, 38.63,
        25.19, 32.11, 26.57, 37.23, 37.97, 27.38, 27.25, 33.33,
        31.41, 26.93, 28.42, 25.99, 30.09, 31.87, 34.40, 33.46,
        31.76, 34.03, 27.01, 27.52, 30.41, 25.84, 25.84]]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()#figsize = (10, 10))
ax.hist(var[0],histtype = 'step')
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

The bug seems to be fixed for `v1.3`, however.  Apparently I'm using an earlier version.

```
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.1.1rc'
```

So upgrading matplotlib will probably fix the problem.

Comment: You are exactly right. Apparently I am using 1.2.1 and the bug remains. Thank you for the fix, it works great.